# How to get a Node position in a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

### TL;DR

How can I retrieve a Node position in a NodeList? Position in the meaning of offset in a zero-based structure, not position as `top` or `left`

---

I have a jQuery UI Draggable/Droppable that fills an Array when a dragged element is dropped. Because it's very simple I use a simple `Array.push()`

When building the UI to show something about the dragged element (a thumbnail for what matters), I retrieve this Array and manipulate the last Node previously created. Regardless of all other possibilities to get the last Node, I'm retrieving it by offset, when it's equal to the number of elements I have already registered:

```
let offset  = mySource.length;

// Sounds like a bathroom >.<

let $item = $( '#data .entry' ).eq( offset ).addClass( 'occupied' );
```

It works, but these elements can, eventually, be removed so the Array must obviously be updated. But to do so I need an offset for, maybe, `Array.slice()`, and I was thinking about (and here comes the question) getting the position of the parent of the clicked element (that triggered the removal action) and use it as offset, since both Array and NodeList are, one way or another, zero-based collections.

Considering a NodeList structure like this:

```css
.fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="data">

  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah #1
      <span class="fa fa-trash" title="Remove"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah #2
      <span class="fa fa-trash" title="Remove"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah #3
      <span class="fa fa-trash" title="Remove"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah #4
      <span class="fa fa-trash" title="Remove"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="entry">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor blah blah blah #5
      <span class="fa fa-trash" title="Remove"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

How could I get the position of the Node `.entry` inside the `#data` when its child `.fa` is clicked?

Comment: Really not clear what node you want to index or how this array gets created. A demo would likely help. Note that `droppable` plugin gives you access to the dragged element in event callbacks

Comment: Would it be simpler to use native live NodeList?

Comment: That's not a node list but a jQuery collection. Which has an [`index` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/). Though to remove it (create another collection without it), you'll want to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: My mistake then. I assumed it was a node list because, well, it's a bunch of nodes. But in the end I knew it was a collection, that's what matters (:p) but I didn't know about this `index()` method. About removing it, this is just a pseudo-code, of course. In the real UI I'll just remove a class (`occupied`) that tells the whole drag n' drop that something can be dropped in there and then render a thumbnail of whatever has been dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I get the position of the Node .entry inside the #data when its child .fa is clicked?

Use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to the parent entry and get it's [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$('#data .entry .fa').click(function(){
   // target entry instance
   var $entry = $(this).closest('.entry');
   // get entry instance index amongst it's siblings
   var entryIndex = $entry.index();    
});
```

Comment: Hmm... That method `index()` sounds really what I'm looking for and, in fact, In the pseudo-code I've created for the question it works perfect, with Babel or without it, but when applying to the real HTML, that has a lot of more markup because of Bootstrap, every click return zero. I must be traversing it wrongly. Could you help me based on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nccxpamg/)?

Comment: Well, in my UI, using exactly as you posted didn't work. But with the knowledge of the `index()` method, after reading its docs, I came to something similar to to this: `$('#data .entry').index( $entry )`, which is pretty much like using `offset()` but for a unknown position. Thank you for the help